`realpath --relative-to=~` not resolving ~
I stumbled across a very confusing result while trying to programmatically get the path to a particular directory from home.
$ realpath --relative-to=~ /home/self/.local/share/package
../../../../..
$ realpath --relative-to=~ /home/self/.local/share/
../../../../../..
$ realpath --relative-to=~ /home/self/.local/
../../../../../../..
$ realpath --relative-to=~ /home/self/
../../../../../../../..

I finally realized that it is interpreting ~ as the name of a file/directory in my wd.
$ pwd
/home/self/.local/share/package/path/to/working/directory
$ realpath --relative-to=`pwd`/file /home/self/
../../../../../../../..

My question is, why is ~ not being resolved to my home directory? I thought that this resolution happened entirely in the shell, prior to the command even receiving it, similar to env vars or globbing.
$ realpath --relative-to=$HOME ~
.
$ fn() { echo $1 : $2 : $3 }; fn * ~
file_in_wd1 : file_in_wd2 : file_in_wd3    # NOT: * : ~ :
$ fn '*' '~'
* : ~ :

I am using zsh, although I can't find any settings I've manually set where flipping the setting changes this behavior. In bash, I see the same behavior. Same with sh, which on my machine is owned by my bash package, but has different behavior (I suspect there's an option somewhere to force bash into posix-compliance).
Can anyone explain what is happening here, or what fundamental aspect of my understanding of how the shell works is incorrect?

Quoting the answer there: "zsh has a magicequalsubst option for tilde expansion to be performed after unquoted equal signs (=) though"

Superb, yes, that does answer my question. I honestly did search before making this post, but I had started by searching for things about realpath, as I assumed that was the source of the weirdness. But as I continued to write the post and explore possibilities, I realized it was more likely related to the shell than the particular command, and did not search again at that point (when I likely would have found the answer you reference or similar). Thank you for the help, it explains quite a bit.
